# Re-populating mongoose document after save

Tags: mongoose, populate

I have tried looking at other questions on SO, but they are all a bit out of date. I am using Mongoose to save a change to a document. I would like to be able to repopulate the reference fields I have. I saw in the Mongoose issues [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/570) and [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/1292) that something like this had been added, but I can't seem to get it to work unless I manually "depopulate" the fields, populate using the model, and then saving the doc.

For example, if I had a schema like this that references another collection:

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    Name: {
        type: String
        required: true
    },
    Manager: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Managers'
    }
});
```

And the populated object looks something like this:

```
{
    Name: 'Test Employee',
    Manager: {
        _id: <Some ObjectId>
        Name: 'Test Manager',
        Group: 'HR'
    }
}
```

If I change the ID value of the manager and then call `employee.save(callback)`, the returned data only has the correct ID, but has not repopulated the `Manager` field with the new Manager. Is there a way to quickly do this without all of the steps I described above?

Comment: I suspect you will get more useful answers if you post some code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what normally happens in the scenario where you want to change an employees manager would be:

- load the employee model. You may not need to populate the manager at this point if you just intend to change it without really using the existing manager value. Make sure you change it with `employee.manager = newManager` and not `employee.manager._id = newManagerId` otherwise I'm not sure mongoose will properly understand your change.
- change the manager on the in-memory model. However, just keep your reference to this instance available so you don't have to re-fetch it from the DB.
- save the employee with the new manager ID
- If you want to do more with the populated employee (send it to the browser or whatever), just use your existing reference from step 2 instead of refetching.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I might be able to refactor it to do that, but it is using data coming from a user, so the data I get back is already populated. Just changing the ID in the populated model does work, it just doesn't repopulate.